# SQL Server Profiler behavior?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, profiler

I want to monitor only sp's.

Does SQL Server Profiler listen to *all* events and *then* filters the desired data (e.g. sp's)?

Or rather the sql *emits  only* Profiler pre-configured events ?

Comment: See the SQL Trace Architecture (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187933(v=SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: @ThomasStringer I didnt understand from it if it _emits_ all event from event source !

Comment: _After an event occurs, if the event class has been included in a trace definition..._ trace definition can contain (or not) event to listen. but does the event source  EMITS IT at first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Trace (what Profiler is built on) will capture all instances of any events that you decide to collect. So if you collect RPC:Completed events, you'll get an event for every RPC completed, trace will be capturing that event. If you don't select that event, trace won't be grabbing it. So it will only capture what it is told to.

You can (and should) then further filter the data returned by adding filters on various columns (say a database name or a duration for a completed event to capture only events with a duration of greater than a certain value, for example). In that case, all of the instances of that event are still captured, but the filter is then applied before the information is dumped to the mechanism you are using to trace.

See the difference? If you don't select the event, that event isn't captured or sent (Emitted as you are saying, if I comprehend you correctly), but if you do select the event - all instances are captured but only those that pass the filter criteria are sent (emitted).

I would also argue against using profiler but consider doing a Server Side trace to a file. Look at this [blog post from Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events) to show the difference in performance impact between the methods.

Comment: _If you don't select the event, that event isn't captured or sent_ that helped. So if i do not select to monitor sp's , sql server **will not throw events for sp's right?** ( i dont care about who is catching those event , i just care if sql throw events of sp's)

Comment: ps there is a difference in your answer between captured or sent ( it is not the same thing). Sql throws a ball(an sp has executed). I dont care who is catching the ball( trace) I just ask if sql trully throws the ball.(sending) even if there is no one to get the ball.

Comment: If you don't select the event, I don't believe it is thrown. No. Those aren't always firing that I know of behind the scenes, and it isn't actually a terribly important question for when you are capturing data. If it is always throwing them in some way behind the scenes it is how SQL is always running anyway.. but the answer as far as I am aware is - no.. They are only thrown if you tell SQL to by capturing that event, which is what I said in my answer.

Comment: Thanks mike.  i truly hope it doesn't throw if it wasn't told to...:-)